# How to identify AVAudioPlayer is streaming the song

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I am playing a song with AVAudioPlayer. Actually I am  streaming the song from server database with help of url. like this

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myAudioURl"];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];    
  audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
```

while retrieving it takes few seconds.. So want to rotate ActivityIndicator until the song play. How i can do this??

Comment: I think you need to call 'play' method in order to start playing song. It doesn't start direct play..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:

`NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`

This is one of the worst possible ways to download data on iOS, for a number of reasons. Firstly, it's synchronous, so if you're calling it on the main thread it's a blocking operation (meaning your entire UI will freeze). What only takes a few seconds on a fast WiFi connection could take a minute or longer on a cellular connection.

It's also bad because it doesn't provide you with any sort of progress or status update. If the download fails you won't know *why* it's gone wrong. You'll be in the dark as to whether it's your user's network connection, the server, something completely different...

So even if you were running `dataWithContentsOfURL` on a background thread, it's still far from ideal since it doesn't provide you with any error handling or progress updates.

A far, far better way is to use `NSURLConnection`, which provides block based asynchronous downloading methods along with completion *and* failure handlers. Many developers prefer to use a higher level abstraction of `NSURLConnection`, such as the popular `AFNetworking`. There are many questions here on StackOverflow relating to best practices using both of these.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer... will you please provide any links regarding online streaming the song